# How to delete Google Sheet rows which are old entries as per definition in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google Sheet which tracks weekly project work of the team. Sometimes, team members make edits to the **same project in the same project week** which creates new project rows rather than overwriting the existing project (because it's not a dup but rather an edit to an existing row). I want to find a better way to remove "old entries" as per definition below.

Here is the current way the sheet looks along with the desired state:
[image]

**The rule which I declare as a duplicate/old entry looks like this:**

1. Find rows that have the same Full Name and same Project Name. [Lisa, Email Campaign]
2. For those, check all rows where timestamps are between the minimum timestamp and any upcoming Sunday. [8/21/2020, 8/22/2020 - 8/23/2020]
3. Take the row with the latest timestamp and delete all other ones [8/22/2020 is the last edited entry in that work week which I want].

How would I approach this? Can I stay within Google Sheets and use formulas or do I need to use App Scripts/Java Script? Any recommendations are appreciated.

Comment: You could probably do with them both. Both have individual advantages and disadvantages.

Comment: Here's the google app script reference for deleting individual responses to a form: 
 https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#deleteResponse(String)

Answer (score 0):

Google formulas can't delete rows but you could use them to find which rows should be deleted, by the other hand Google Apps Script could be used to delete rows.

Resource

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets